# Unable to get Enum Value on my response JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, enums, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building flask project for my learning now, now I have simple schema for Employees like this (Didn't added all column names):

```
class GenderChoices(enum.Enum):
    M = 'M'
    F = 'F'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @staticmethod
    def from_string(s):
        try:
            return GenderChoices[s]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError()


class Employees(db.Model):
    ___tablename___ = "employees"

    emp_no = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    gender = db.Column(db.Enum(GenderChoices, values_callable=lambda x: [str(member.value)
                                                                         for member in GenderChoices]))
```

Basic Arguments on resources side, I am passing like that:

```
parser.add_argument('gender',
                    type=GenderChoices.from_string,
                    help='This field cannot be blank',
                    required=True,
                    choices=list(GenderChoices))
```

As I am showing my response like this:

```
return {
            'message': 'New Employee Has been created',
            'Employee_Details': {
                'employee_id': new_id,
                'gender': data['gender']
            }
        }, 201
```

While running my script to add Employees runs fine and it stores data on my database as well, but on showing my result on postman, I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type GenderChoices is not JSON serializable
```

What seems to be problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Flask-RESTful

If you are using Flask-RESTful, you can force the conversion to a string by using the `@marshal_with` decorator and specifying a `field.String`.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    request
)
from flask_restful import (
    Api, 
    Resource, 
    fields, 
    marshal_with, 
    reqparse
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import enum 


class GenderChoices(enum.Enum):
    M = 'M'
    F = 'F'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @staticmethod
    def from_string(s):
        try:
            return GenderChoices[s]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY='your secret here', 
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///demo.db', 
)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('gender',
    type=GenderChoices.from_string,
    help='This field cannot be blank',
    required=True,
    choices=list(GenderChoices)
)

class Employee(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "employees"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    gender = db.Column(db.Enum(GenderChoices, values_callable=lambda x: [str(member.value) for member in GenderChoices]))

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

class EmployeeList(Resource):
    @marshal_with({
        'message': fields.String,
        'Employee_Details': fields.Nested({
            'employee_id': fields.Integer, 
            'gender': fields.String 
        })
    })
    def post(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        employee = Employee(**args)
        db.session.add(employee)
        db.session.commit()
        return {
            'message': 'New Employee Has been created',
            'Employee_Details': {
                'employee_id': employee.id,
                'gender': employee.gender
            }
        }, 201

api.add_resource(EmployeeList, '/employees')
```

###### Flask

When using pure flask you can use the following variants.

On the one hand, you can use a [`StrEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.StrEnum) whose values can be converted to JSON without any action.

```py
class GenderChoices(enum.StrEnum):
    M = 'M'
    F = 'F'
```

If you want to use an alternative method, you can create a custom [`JSONProvider`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.json.provider.JSONProvider) and use that in your application. The following example extends the [`DefaultJSONProvider`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.json.provider.DefaultJSONProvider).

```py
from flask.json.provider import DefaultJSONProvider

class CustomJSONProvider(DefaultJSONProvider):
    @staticmethod
    def default(o):
        if isinstance(o, enum.Enum):
            return o.name
        return DefaultJSONProvider.default(o)


app = Flask(__name__)
app.json_provider_class = CustomJSONProvider
app.json = CustomJSONProvider(app)
```

Comment: I am unable to understand your comment here.. How and where I can use this implementation?

Comment: If you use `StrEnum`, there is no problem converting to JSON anyway. However, if you stick with your implementation of the enum and use a `JSONProvider` you have to assign it to the instance of your application.

Comment: I implemented your logic, nothing happened... Same result.. May be you are confusing my concern.. Results are storing perfectly fine on database, its on postman, when I want to return a result, that gender is creating a problem.. and seems like serialising is the only solution.

Comment: Sorry, my version runs under Flask, but you use Flask-RESTful right?

Comment: I have expanded my answer and hope to meet your requirements.

Comment: Yes, I am using flask-restful..

Comment: I have used your flask-restful method, since I am using that, its still showing me that error.. @Detlef

Comment: I tested it in various ways with Postman and the error message no longer occurs for me when I use `enum.StrEnum` or `@marshal_with`.

Comment: Well Finally, your solution work perfectly fine now.,. :).. Now I am having another issue... Gonna put another question