# Getting null responses while using marshal_with for getting data

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

So, I am working on my self learning on flask, in order to one my problem with enums, I am using `marshal_with`, [which one of user suggested me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77188182/unable-to-get-enum-value-on-my-response-json).. Now I have problem getting data for invalid ids..

I am using following to get response:

```
def json(self):
    return {
        'data': {
            'employee_id': self.emp_no,
            'employee_name': self.first_name + " " + self.last_name,
            'gender': self.gender,
            'birth_date': self.birth_date,
            'hire_date': self.hire_date,
            'created_at': self.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
            'last_updated_at': self.last_updated_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        }
    }

@classmethod
def find_by_employee_id(cls, employee_id):
    return cls.query.filter_by(emp_no=employee_id).first()
```

at resources section of employees, I have implemented following logic to get results for end point:

```
class GetEmployee(Resource):
    @marshal_with({
        'data': fields.Nested({
            'employee_id': fields.Integer,
            'employee_name': fields.String,
            'gender': fields.String,
            'birth_date': fields.String,
            'hire_date': fields.String,
            'created_at': fields.Raw,
            'last_updated_at': fields.Raw
        })
    })
    def get(self, employee_id: int):
        employee = Employees.find_by_employee_id(employee_id)
        if not employee:
            return {'message': 'Employee Not Found'}, 404

        return employee.json(), 200
```

Now good thing is, I am getting response perfectly fine, if I am entering valid `employee_id` within end point, but if I add invalid id like 4,5, I am getting response like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "employee_id": 0,
        "employee_name": null,
        "gender": null,
        "birth_date": null,
        "hire_date": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "last_updated_at": null
    }
}
```

what I am expecting is the response, which I have added within `GetEmployee` class, i.e.

```
{'message': 'Employee Not Found'}
```

Where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the possibility of throwing a 404 error when querying the database if no entry is found. It is also possible to define an error message that is output when `abort` is called automatically following the error. The explanation can be found in the Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation in the ["Queries for Views"](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/queries/#queries-for-views) section.

The following example shows you in a simplified manner how you can output either the error or the resource. Of course, it is also possible to call `abort()` manually if necessary.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    request
)
from flask_restful import (
    Api, 
    Resource, 
    fields, 
    marshal_with, 
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property
import enum 


class GenderChoices(enum.Enum):
    M = 'M'
    F = 'F'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY='your secret here', 
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///demo.db', 
)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
api = Api(app)

class Employee(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "employees"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)
    name = column_property(firstname + ' ' + lastname)
    
    gender = db.Column(db.Enum(
        GenderChoices, 
        values_callable=lambda x: [str(member.value) for member in GenderChoices]
    ))
    
    # ...

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'employee_id': self.id,
            'employee_name': self.name,
            'gender': self.gender
            # ...
        }

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    employee = Employee(
        firstname='User', 
        lastname='One', 
        gender=GenderChoices.M,
    )
    db.session.add(employee)
    db.session.commit()

class EmployeeRsrc(Resource):
    @marshal_with({
        'data': fields.Nested({
            'employee_id': fields.Integer, 
            'employee_name': fields.String,  
            'gender': fields.String 
            # ...
        })
    })
    def get(self, employee_id):
        employee = db.get_or_404(
            Employee, employee_id, 
            description='Employee Not Found'
        )
        return {
            'data': employee.to_dict()
        }

api.add_resource(EmployeeRsrc, '/employees/<employee_id>')
```

If you want to output any error message including a status code, you can use `abort(code, *args, **kwargs)`. Execution ends immediately and an exception is thrown, which is caught by the error handler, which sends a response.

```py
from flask_restful import abort

class MyRsrc(Resource):
    def post(self):
        # ...
        abort(422, message='Email invalid')
```

Comment: Man, it really worked.. Thanks for that.. But thats just for one condition, lets say, if I have to add some other method, i.e. invalid email or invalid date format, then what should I do?

Comment: Also what I can see, is that I have only 404, but what I have to show 403 or 401 status.. then what?

Comment: @qatesterbecomingprogrammer Unfortunately, the Flask-RESTful documentation is incomplete, so I can't give you a link to the function. I tried to add an explanation to my answer. The behavior is the same as in a standard Flask endpoint